# Tinymce 4.3 : How to move captioned image?

Tags: tinymce-4

I am using tinymce 4.3.7 , it works great but have few issues with images.I did following configuarations to set tinymce on textarea

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: '.tiny-area',
        plugins: [
            "image"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | fontselect | fontsizeselect | forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link jbimages",
        image_caption: true,
});
```

**Issues are:**

1. I am unable to move an image once I give caption, I can't reposition it (which was possible before giving caption)
2. Some times it creates image copy on dragging

How I can move the captioned image in tinymce editor??